# jQuery .prepend JSON results to multiple div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I am looping through some JSON and prepending latest results to some HTML on another page. Everything works perfectly code wise, except I am currently prepending everything to one div, where I would like to prepend particular items to particular divs. See below. I would like to echo the name in the name div, content in content div and the id in the message div, for example.

Thanks so much in advance!

My HTML is as follows:

```
 <div id="activityspot">
   <div class="entry template"> 
     <div class="message"></div> 
     <div class="name"></div>
     <div class="content"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery is as follows:

```
$.get(url, function(data) {
  jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);

  var spot = $("#activityspot");
  var template = spot.find(".template");

for (var j = 0; j < jsonData.items.length; j++) 
{
  var entryData = jsonData.items[j];
  var entry = template.clone();
  entry.removeClass("template");

  //I guess I need to select the other div's in here?

  entry.find(".message").text(entryData.statusid + entryData.name + entryData.content); 
  spot.prepend(entry);
}
```

What I end up with is something that looks like this:

```
 <div class="message">53671 (id) Billy Zane (name) I like Billy (message) </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
entry.find(".message").text(entryData.statusid); 
entry.find(".name").text(entryData.name); 
entry.find(".content").text(entryData.content);
```